# Any mention of Hakhel in Neviim or Ktuvim?

Tags: tanach, hakhel

It appears that [Hakhel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakhel) is only mentioned in Dvarim 31:10-12 and Talmud.

Is it ever mentioned in Tanakh outside of the Torah (i.e., Prophets or Writings)?

E.g., "such and such king observed/failed to observe the Mitzvah".

Comment: Gersonides to II Kings 23 implies that they got the idea to have the king stand on a stage from _hakhel_. (Not that they actually fulfilled _hakhel_ in that chapter, though.)

Comment: The talmud talks rather frequently about it - most recently in daf yomi at the end of Sotah (I think ~45) where it discusses Agrippas standing during his recitation and breaking down crying when he realizes he is unfit for the throne. Bad Things ensue.